# Is there a benefit to creating multiple Xcode projects vs multiple targets?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I am building a few static c++ libraries: lib1 relies on nothing, lib2 and lib3 rely on lib1, and lib4 relies on lib1 and lib3. Finally, the goal is to have a all of these compiled into a single framework for easy consumption.

As a fledgling mac developer, I am interested in the right way (if one exists) to organize these libraries within Xcode. My thoughts are to have 1 project per library, and a project containing the other 4 projects and builds into the framework, but I've also seen situations where only a single project exists, with different files compiled per target.

Is there a 'best practice' here, or any significant benefits of one option over the other? Or is this just a style decision?

Comment: If they're different libs, you just can't use targets. Targets are for shared codebases with different build settings. Subprojects might be ideal, if you want to be able to debug seamlessly between them (eg debugging lib1's code while you're running on lib2's).

Comment: Understood. Related: if lib1 has header files associated with it, should they be in the container project? Or is there some way to say 'export these headers with the target' so other libs built in the same container have access to them?

Comment: If you're using subproject, you'll need to configure the header search path of the container project so that it can find the headers of the subproject. 

Note that you don't have to change anything in the subproject, and it can be compiled independently, if you choose to do so.

iOS 8 has something called 'embedded framework', but haven't tried that out...

Comment: Sounds good - if you care to copy the above to answer I can accept this question as resolved i think.

Answer (score 0):

We can reduce the number of times the code is used. If there is a project with multiple brands, we can create different brands of products by adding multiple targets. At this time there is a need to change the same thing which should be done according to different brands.